# NSView as child of NSWindow.contentView lose interaction

Tags: swift, macos, window, nsview, nswindow

I have an issue where my `NSView` does not respond to mouse events and interactions.
If the `NSView` is the `NSWindow.contentView`, it works.
If the `NSView` is added as a child view of the default `NSWindow.contentView`, we can't interact with it (mouse events don't work).
I need the second option as my `NSView` isn't shorter that the `NSWindow` and I need to center it in it (therefore I need to add constraints on a intermediate view: The default `contentView` in this case).

Here is a reproductible example:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Clicked me baby, one more time!")
            }
        .background(.red)
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let window = NSWindow()
        let view = NSHostingView(rootView: MyView())
        view.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 50,y: 50))
        let wrapperView = NSView()
        
        wrapperView.addSubview(view)
        window.contentView?.addSubview(wrapperView) // <-- This doesn't work
        //window.contentView = wrapperView          // <-- This work
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.setIsVisible(true)
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `wrapperView`? Is the value of `wrapperView.frame.size` `(width = 0, height = 0)`? Have you tried adding constraints?

Comment: Because I don't know how to add constraints related to the window. I need my view centered in the window (dynamically). The only way I found to do that is by adding a intermediate view and add my constraints related to it.

Comment: You have to add constraints between `view` and `wrapperView` and constraints between `wrapperView` and `window.contentView`.

Comment: I think I tried but I didn’t have the mouse events either. Will try again when I get back home.